# Android app lifecycle Up and Back

Tags: android, android-activity, backup, task, instance

I have an app with some normal behaviour but I still dont know what I am doing wrong.

Activity A calls --> Activity B
I pass strings/ints from one activity to the other (Intent.putExtra())
I had declared my activities as single instances and declared who is parent of who in my manifest, but when I open other app and then go back to mine, the activity I was in is the only still alive.
If I remove the'singleInstance', then my navigation works but the ones that receive strings from the intent (previous activity) crashes.

I want to be able to:

- When I am in my app, navigate up/back through my activities.
- If I leave my app and come back, still be able to navigate up/back in my app.

Considering I pass values between activities with Intent.putExtra("key", "value")

I think is all related with the Back/Up Navigation and the android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" | "singleTask" | "singleInstance"] but I can't find the perfect solution.

Update:
A --> B --> C
A->B: A putExtra; B getExtra
B->C: B put Extra; C get extra

If I go to C, leave the App and then come back to the app, the app is in C, and if I try to navigate up to B, it crashes because I don't have the extras and the activity has been terminated.
What is the best behaviour? Keep them open? Recreate them?

Comment: Why don't you focus on what crashes, rather than "fixing" it by changing the intent flags?

Comment: Because the way I had it working wasnt allowing me to navigate through my app after I get out of it and come back, which means something is wrong even tho its doesnt crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the behaviour you're trying to achieve is the default behaviour on Android. So I believe that on your question, less is more.

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

- remove all `parentActivityName` from it. It really does not much at all.
- remove all `launchMode` those specific edge cases, unless you have a specific reason and a non-default behaviour, do not use them.

`intent` parameters you're passing to activities don't get messed by any of those manifest details, I don't think they have anything to do with your issue. On any activity you should be able to call `getIntent().getExtras()` and access any parameters passed to it, no matter how many times you exit and enter the app.

you do not need to save/restore the intent parameters during `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. Those callbacks are for current state, not for parameters passed to it. Those are different things.

- `back`: that happens automatically. You cannot `finish();` the previous activity when calling the next one.
- `up`: it's just a matter of overriding the `onOptionsItemSelected`

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
      // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
      case android.R.id.home:
            finish(); // this finishes and the previous will be shown.
      return;
       // other menu items ?
      }
  }

> if I try to navigate up to B, it crashes because I don't have the
>   extras and the activity has been terminated. What is the best
>   behaviour? Keep them open? Recreate them?

do **NEVER** say "it crashes" on StackOverflow without providing a stacktrace and the lines of code around that stacktrace. That's one of the main reasons I downvote people.

If it crashes, ask about that crash, do not mess-up the automatically-default navigation to "try to fix it"

Comment: Will do for the next time. 
Your solution worked actually, removed all and I just do UP with BACK button. Now, I wonder if that navigation UP in the APP is correct, or not. I mean, do users get that to go up you have to press back?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you must set condition in second activity example on String data:

```
if(intent != null){
yourString = intent.getStringExtra("count");
}
```

then you must provide saving instance like

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("count", yourString);//or int or other look on developers
  }
```

and restoring from instance

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    yourString = savedInstanceState.getString("count");
  }
```

Comment: This looks much better. I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

The up button takes you to the previous activity hierarchically in the same app.
The back button takes you to the previous screen/app/activity that your phone was on, irregardless of which app it belonged to.